# List of important commands to have an idea of settings for future reference

Tags: linux, centos, backup

I want to keep the settings of my linux machines in github etc to have an idea of file locations, firewall rules, network settings and any other critical settings.
What I remember are the following, however I believe I will be missing more and will highly appreciate more commands to save.

```
#!/bin/bash
machine=$(hostname -f)
mkdir log_$machine
du -hs /* &> log_$machine/DiskUsage_root_$machine.log
ls -altr /home &> log_$machine/ls_home_$machine.log
ls -altr /data &> log_$machine/ls_data_$machine.log
ls -altr /data/Install &> log_$machine/ls_Install_$machine.log
tree -C -L 1 / &> log_$machine/tree_root_$machine.log
tree -C -L 1 /data &> log_$machine/tree_data_$machine.log
tree -C -L 1 /data/Install &> log_$machine/tree_data_$machine.log
tree -C -L 1 /home &> log_$machine/tree_home_$machine.log
ifconfig &> log_$machine/networkSettings_$machine.log
crontab -l &> log_$machine/crontab_$machine.log
cat /etc/fstab &> log_$machine/fstab_$machine.log
iptables-save &> log_$machine/firewall_$machine.log
route -n &> log_$machine/gateway_route_$machine.log
cat /etc/bashrc &> log_$machine/etc_bashrc_$machine.log
cat /proc/cpuinfo &> log_$machine/proc_cpuinfo_$machine.log
uname -a &> log_$machine/uname_$machine.log
netstat -antp &> log_$machine/netstat_$machine.log
free -m -h &> log_$machine/ram_$machine.log
fdisk -l | grep Disk &> log_$machine/fdisk_$machine.log
dmidecode -t system &> log_$machine/dmidecode_$machine.log
tar -czf log_$machine.tgz log_$machine
```

Comment: If you're managing multiple servers, I strongly recommend using configuration management software such as puppet, ansible or chef. When properly set up you'll be able to recreate any one server from scratch without manual intervention. (And all config management files should naturally be in a version-controlled repository.)

Comment: You are right. At the moment I only have around 6 servers but that will be the way forward in my new job starting from 1st November :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply back up the whole `/etc`? That's where *most* of the system-wide configuration is stored. You may also want to backup `/var/lib` and `$HOME/.config`. Or use a proper backup solution of course!

And for all those `tree` and `ls -lr` commands ... they can be replaced with ad-hoc `locate` to find files you need, e.g.

```
~ $ locate .bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/home/ipx/.bashrc
...
```

(You may need to install `mlocate` or `findutils-locate` package).

I guess that's a better way than storing some random file listings on github.

Comment: Yes, saving `/etc`, `/home`, `/var` and mysqldump of all databases are already taken but I want something simple to give you an idea of where things were and which device was mounted where.
During troubleshooting or looking /etc/ after an year is not a good site I think.